# Ектинья может быть просительной?

Tags: выбор-слов, церковная-лексика

В одном только словаре нашла, что ектинья (ектиния) уже содержит в себе просьбу и что она - часть богослужения, т. е. (если я правильно поняла) не может быть от частного лица:

[ЕКТИНЬЯ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/11131/%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%AC%D0%AF)

> < греч. ekteneia усердие.
>
> Часть православного богослужения: молитва,
> содержащая просьбы и обращения к Богу.

У меня:

> А ещё в голове теперь часто звучат **слова просительной ектеньи**:
> кончины безболезненной, непостыдной у Господа просим. Кстати, пора бы
> знать наизусть…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки нет. Энциклопедический словарь утверждает:

> ЕКТЕНЬЯ (от греческого ekteneia — усердие), молитвенные прошения в
>   православном богослужении. **Главные виды: великая, малая, сугубая и
>   просительная.** Первые две, так называемые мирные, провозглашаются
>   дьяконом (или священником) после возгласа: “Миром Господу помолимся!”.

https://illustrated_dictionary.academic.ru/3803/%D0%95%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F

Так что это религиозный термин - просительная ектенья.

Comment: А частное лицо свою импровизированную молитву - дома, во время землетрясения - может назвать *просительная ектенья?* Или *просительная* и есть частная?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Не выдумывайте, это слова НЕ частного лица. Это канонический **текст** молитвы.  .

Comment: Ектения   - не вся молитва, а перечень молитвенных просьб - последняя просительная часть, она произносится во время большинства церковных богослужений, а в частности во время Литургии. Аналогичные по смыслу обращения содержатся и в других религиозных текстах. Например, в молитве, адресованной Иоанну Воину, также есть слова о «непостыдной и мирной» смерти, а также о «Тайн Божиих причастныя». Вероятно, Ваш герой не знает текста молитвы, импровизирует, а просительную ектенью вспомнил. А частная молитва или в храме священником читается - разницы нет.

Answer (score 2):

Может, вот эта информация поможет?

[Ектения](https://spiritual_culture.academic.ru/773/%D0%95%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) — молитва, содержащая прошение к Богу о чем-то вечном и земном. Главные прошения: наставить на молитву, на добрые дела, на мирную и безгрешную **жизнь**, на успешность деяний, на **прощение** грехов, на **помощь** в сложной ситуации. Ектения входит в церковные богослужения, но также входит в утренние и вечерние молитвы, совершаемые дома... Есть разные ектении: великая, сугубая, малая, просительная, а также ектении оглашенных и умерших. Верующим человеком ектении произносятся часто в течении дня, как обращение к Богу в больших и малых делах. Существуют, например, ектении на успешность учения.

[Православная Энциклопедия](http://www.pravenc.ru/text/189661.html):
На литургии просительные ектении, принимающие в свой состав дополнительные прошения, читаются после великого входа и после анафоры.

[Ектения просительная](https://www.novgorod.ru/read/information/cultutre/singing/liturgy/ecteniya-pleading/):
*Христианския кончины живота нашего, безболезненны, непостыдны, мирны, и добраго ответа на Страшнем Судищи Христове, просим.*

Дома, во время катаклизма и бесконечного страха — у каждого свои, особые слова в обращении ко Всевышнему. Эти, думаю, могут быть словами просительной ектении.